# How to get the count of each unique value in a column between two dates?

Tags: sql

I need to write a SQL query which will return a list of unique values in a column, along with the count of how many times that value appears and I need to be able to specify a date range for the count.

The query will be ran against a sales order table to see which user has raised the most sales orders between two dates.

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as 'Total'
FROM so_table
WHERE user_id in ('John', 'Michelle', 'Lewis', 'Karl', 'Tom')
GROUP BY user_id
```

This is the code I have so far, I've tried selecting date_entered but I can't figure out what I need to do to be able to get the count between two dates.

Thank you for any responses and apologies if anything is unclear.

Comment: Hint:  `where date_entered >= '2019-01-01' and date_entered < '2019-02-01'` for January 2019.

Comment: Doh! I assumed (I know, I shouldn't have) that I wouldn't be able to specify the between dates without them being returned in the select itself! Thank you very much.

Comment: `as 'Total'`  is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can input the dates and it should work.

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as 'Total'
FROM so_table
WHERE user_id in ('John', 'Michelle', 'Lewis', 'Karl', 'Tom')
AND date_entered>= Start_Date
AND date_entered<= End_Date
GROUP BY user_id
```